# Javascript no actualiza un div despues de una consulta a mysql

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

Tengo un codigo que pertenece a un aplicativo de un calendario en el que se puden añadir eventos y con javascript se actualiza el calendario. El problema es que no consigo que se actualize despues de insertar datos en la base de datos. Por lo que creo la orden para actualizar el calendario se executa antes que la insercion de los datos en la base de datos. Cual podria ser el sistema para retrasar la actualizacion de los datos? O tengo que pensar en un sistema diferente de trabajo?

Este es el código:

```
   function crearRodaTorns(){
   $.showMsg({
    msg: "<?php echo $Text['pregunta_roda'];?>"+idData+"<?php echo $Text['pregunta_roda2'];?>",
    buttons: {
    "<?=$Text['btn_ok'];?>":function(){
        let dataTorn = idData.split("-").reverse().join("-");
        let parametres = {
            oper : "crearRodaTorns",
            data : dataTorn,
        };
```

**Esta primera consulta en ajax es la que actualiza los datos.
La consulta a mysql funciona perfectamente y se insertan los nuevos datos.**

```
        $.ajax({
            data: parametres,
            url: 'php/ctrl/Calendar.php',
            type: 'post',
            success:  function (response) {
               $('#contenidorTorn').html("<h1><?php echo $Text['roda_torns_creada'];?></h1>");
                let parametresCalendari = {
                oper : "actualitzarCalendari",
                mes : dataTorn.split("-")[1],
                any : dataTorn.split("-")[0],
        };
```

**Esta es la consulta para actualizar el calendario. Imprime el calendario perfectamente pero sin actualizar los datos. Si actualizo el navegador si que me imprime perfectamente los datos nuevos en el calendario.**

```
        $.ajax({
                data:  parametresCalendari,
                url:   'php/ctrl/Calendar.php',
                type:  'post',
                success:  function (response) {
                    $('#contenidorCalendari').html(response);
                }
        });
            }
        });
        $(this).dialog("close");
    },
    "<?=$Text['btn_cancel'];?>" : function(){
        $( this ).dialog( "close" );
    }
},
type: 'confirm'});
}
```

Comment: ¿Y si pones el segundo ajax dentro de una función que se ejecute en el success del primero tambien te pasa?

Comment: En una funcion no lo he comprovado pero si que he provado insertar el código del segundo ajax en el interior del success del primero y sigue sin actualizarse. Gracias!

Comment: ¿Y si suprimes el segundo ajax y lo procesas todo en el primero y en el php durante la inserción?  Es decir, que el PHP, aparte de insertar, tambien devuelva el calendario actualizado (me refiero sin realizar una segunda llamada ajax)

Comment: Tampoco me ha funcionado. Sigue insertandose bien los datos y si actualizo el navegeador los muestra bien pero no cuando se executa el código. No sé si el error viene porque cuando se executa la actualizacion los datos todavia no han sido insertados o que el código que tengo omite alguna cosa o tiene errores. Gracias por los consejos @masterguru !

Comment: Pues tiene toda la pinta que tu php no devuelve los datos actualizados, y solo se devuelven bien al refrescar la página.  Revisa bien lo que devuelve tu php en la llamada ajax.

Comment: Bueno pues ya he encontrado el problema. He revisado y simplificado el código y el error, torpe por mi parte, lo tenia en la llamada del contenedor que se tenia que recargar. Ahora ya me funciona perfectamente. Aun asi muchas gracias @masterguru por tu tiempo!